# Recognizing if one value is larger or smaller than the second value (C++)

Tags: c++

My Comp Sci teacher gave us 2 basic C++ tasks to do for homework. I've managed to do the first one, but this second one is confusing me. I'm supposed to write code that recognizes if one value is larger than the other, and print out a message saying if one value is larger or not larger than the other. The code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    cout << "Unesi broj" << endl;
    cin >> num1, num2;
    if (num1 > num2) {
        cout << "First number is bigger than the second" << endl; }
    else if (num1 < num2); {
            cout << "First number isn't bigger than the second" << endl;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

If anyone could help me out it'd be amazing, since this is a graded task.

Comment: you cover < and >.  what case are you missing? and why do you have a stray ; after an if() ?

Comment: `cin >> num1, num2;` should be `cin >> num1 >> num2;`

Comment: `else if (num1 < num2);` and remove the `;` here

Comment: if num1 > num2 in the first block of if-clause then you don't need to write an else if, just an else is sufficient. So, num1 > num2 is either true in the first block or False, two options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. `std::cin >> num1, num2;` only affects the first argument. The comma operator doesn't make `std::cin` apply `num2` (More info about how comma operator works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)).
2. `else if (num1 < num2);` does not guard the block `cout << "First number isn't bigger than the second" << endl;` because of the semicolon after the condition so `cout << "First number isn't bigger than the second" << endl;` will always execute.
3. Even if the `else if` guarded the block your solution is wrong when `num1 == num2`: It does not print anything.

**Solutions:**

1. Replace the comma (`,`) with `>>`.
2. Delete the semicolon after `else if (num1 < num2)`.
3. Replace `else if (num1 < num2)` with `else if (num1 <= num2)` or, even better, with `else`.

**Additional information:**

1. `using namespace std;` is considered a bad practice (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

**Full code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    std::cout << "Enter numbers:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;
    if (num1 > num2)
        std::cout << "First number is bigger than the second." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "First number isn't bigger than the second" << std::endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do:

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 ;
```

instead of :

```
cin >> num1,num2;
```